# Detect when textbox value changes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox, setinterval

I have a 2 textboxes.  In the first I type an unique id for a customer.  When I tab out of this textbox it fires a query to my DB and fills the second textbox, which is the customer type.

When the value of the second textbox is updated from the DB (i.e. the value 'changes' from "" to the retrieved value) I want to grab that value and send it as a parameter to my second DB query.

I don't always know how long the first query takes to update the second textbox, so I want to perform the query once the value in the second textbox changes.

Looking at the jQuery .change() event, it appears it only fires when the textbox loses focus, yet in my design, the textbox never gains focus.

Ideally it would be great if I could detect when the second textbox value changes and then fire my 2nd query.

How is this possible?

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve the value you just sent via AJAX? Couldn't you continue your function in javascript when you change the value. Or, even further, do the complete PHP first before sending it back and forth so many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your Ajax call looks like, but you should be able to use [`trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), or simply [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), to trigger the change event-handling:

```
$('#input2').val(variableFromAjaxFunction).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback for your first AJAX request (where you populate the second textbox), trigger the `change` event.

You'll probably have:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  ...
  success: function (response) {
      $('#textbox2').val(response);
  }
});
```

Just change it to:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  ...
  success: function (response) {
      $('#textbox2').val(response).trigger('change');
  }
});
```